# Deleting file attachment on gravity form

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I need to delete the files from the server every 15 days because it is overloaded on my server. So I tried to get all the file url in *wp_rg_lead* and *wp_rg_lead_detail* table. My question is there a hook or filter that can delete the file using the URL only? I know Wordpress has a *wp_delete_attachment* hook, but it is only for the WP media library.

This is my code

```
global $wpdb;
$get_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT tbl2.lead_id, tbl2.form_id,
tbl2.value FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."_rg_lead tbl1 LEFT JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."_rg_lead_detail 
tbl2 ON tbl1.form_id=tbl2.form_id WHERE 
tbl1.date_created < DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 15 DAY) 
AND tbl2.value LIKE '%/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/%' ");

foreach($get_data as $data){
    //delete hook?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of work I tried the `unlink` function of PHP I write it [here](http://www.pjvillanueva.com/remove-the-file-attachment-on-gravity-form/).

```
unlink(path);
```